# Error on getting the result of FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, folderbrowserdialog

Here's my code on my button. I get error on the if statement on the DialogResult. Please see the picture for reference.

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{

}
```

[image: Here's the actualy error]

Comment: Check, may be you have a variable `DialogResult` in your code of `bool?` type?

Comment: hi im new on WPF what do i need to replace or do ?

Comment: @andrew i dont have any variable in this set of codes.

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` returns a `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult`. Use the fully qualified name:

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{

}
```